# MongoDB min query

Tags: mongodb-query

I am fighting bit with min query in the MongoDB. Probably that's not the correct way how to get expected result, but please, help me what am I doing wrong.

Let's assume we have such a data:

```
{ "version": 1, "id": "123-456", "type":"ChangeEvent", "data":"aaa" }
{ "version": 1, "id": "789-987", "type":"ChangeEvent", "data":"aaa" }
{ "version": 2, "id": "123-456", "type":"ChangeEvent", "data":"aaa" }
{ "version": 2, "id": "789-987", "type":"ChangeEvent", "data":"aaa" }
{ "version": 3, "id": "123-456", "type":"AnotherEvent", "data":"aaa" }
{ "version": 4, "id": "123-456", "type":"ChangeEvent", "data":"aaa" }
{ "version": 5, "id": "123-456", "type":"ChangeEvent", "data":"aaa" }
{ "version": 6, "id": "123-456", "type":"ChangeEvent", "data":"aaa" }
{ "version": 7, "id": "123-456", "type":"AnotherEvent", "data":"aaa" }
{ "version": 8, "id": "123-456", "type":"ChangeEvent", "data":"aaa" }
{ "version": 3, "id": "789-987", "type":"ChangeEvent", "data":"aaa" }
{ "version": 9, "id": "123-456", "type":"ChangeEvent", "data":"aaa" }
```

So I have two different ids, and two different types.
What I need to receive is only id `"123-456"` data from latest `"AnotherEvent"` including.

That would mean,

```
{ "version": 7, "id": "123-456", "type":"AnotherEvent", "data":"aaa" }
{ "version": 8, "id": "123-456", "type":"ChangeEvent", "data":"aaa" }
{ "version": 9, "id": "123-456", "type":"ChangeEvent", "data":"aaa" }
```

I thought that using min cursor will help me, concretely this query:

`db.data.find({id: '123-456'}).max( { id: '123-456', type: 'AnotherEvent' } ).hint( { id: 1, type: 1 }).pretty()`

Is this event possible to do directly on the Mongo side through the query?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you saying you want to get all `id: '123-456'` documents where `version` is >= the highest version number for `type: 'AnotherEvent'` (in this case 7)?

Comment: Exactly that :)

Comment: I think you'll need to use two queries then: one to get the highest AnotherEvent version, and a second to get the docs >= that version.

Comment: Yes, I did it like that. But I was looking for better solution, to not query the db twice. If such a solution exists of course.